# Configuring Cognito user pool to send emails with SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses, aws-userpools

This morning, I noticed an alert in my user pool settings that I hadn't noticed before:

[image]

I looked at the settings screen and there's a radio button:

[image]

I already have a from address.  How do I set that setting to Yes with CloudFormation?

The [Cognito CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration) looks like this:

```
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
Properties:
  AdminCreateUserConfig: 
    AdminCreateUserConfig
  AliasAttributes: 
    - String
  AutoVerifiedAttributes: 
    - String
  DeviceConfiguration: 
    DeviceConfiguration
  EmailConfiguration: 
    EmailConfiguration
  EmailVerificationMessage: String
  EmailVerificationSubject: String
  LambdaConfig: 
    LambdaConfig
  MfaConfiguration: String
  Policies: 
    Policies
  Schema: 
    - SchemaAttribute
  SmsAuthenticationMessage: String
  SmsConfiguration: 
    SmsConfiguration
  SmsVerificationMessage: String
  UsernameAttributes: 
    - String
  UserPoolName: String
  UserPoolTags: 
    String: String
```

EmailConfiguration is where I set the from address and I figured maybe they added it there, but the [EmailConfiguration documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration.html) doesn't seem to have anything either.

Any idea how to configure the Cognito User Pool to use SES for emails?

Comment: Did you find out when they started having this?

Comment: @Jun711, no I didn't.  It was shortly before I asked the question.  I mean, within a week or so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been keeping an eye on this issue.  A few days ago, I noticed that the [`AWS::Cognito::UserPool EmailConfiguration` property documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration.html) was updated.  It now includes the `EmailSendingAccount` property.  If you set that to `DEVELOPER`, it will use SES to send emails with the source ARN specified.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this functionality is pretty new. There currently isn't a way to configure this option via Cloud Formation or the sdk. This Functionality will probably become available soon, but in the meantime you can just manually select the option in the dashboard and reconfigure your template once the functionality becomes available.

You could also just wait until it is available if you don't want to manually change any options. However the default cognito email service has a soft limit of 50 emails a day, more details here: [cognito limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html). So depending on your use case waiting might not be an option.